# Character not in repertoire UTF8

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, character

I am working with some japanese text in UTF8, it works very fine except a very rare case. I want to insert the UTF8 text in a PostgreSQL DB (tried on MySQL too), but i got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERREUR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0x2e 0x2e
```

I checked many ways the text and it seems correct UTF8 (tried with mb_check_encoding PHP function and a homemade C). I tried also on many online converters like this one : http://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php

Anyway, i can't detect what character is corresponding to **0xe3 0x2e 0x2e**

Here is the japanese text (given in UTF8 by the Facebook Graph API) : http://pasted.co/0eaea393

I already found 3 differents texts (on thousands) giving this error when trying to insert in SQL. The problematic character is still the same every time : **0xe3 0x2e 0x2e**

After hours, i am now requesting your help...

Comment: E3 2E 2E isn't a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.  The continuation bytes should be in the range 80-BF; 2E is ASCII for `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) rules, a valid  sequence of 3 bytes must be like:

> 1110xxxx  10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx

where `1`, `0` are fixed bits and `x` represent bits that may have a value of `1` or `0`.

Your sequence `0xe3 0x2e 0x2e` is, in binary:

> 11100011 **0**0101110 **0**0101110

The first `0` I've put in boldface should be a `1` for the sequence to be valid, according to the pattern above. The second `0` in boldface, too, is another wrong digit according to UTF-8.

So **it's invalid**.

Besides, php's `mb_check_encoding()` would report it as invalid too, so your php check is probably wrong. Try this:

```
<?php
$bytes = pack("H*", "E32E2E");
$res = mb_check_encoding($bytes, "UTF-8");
if ($res)
  echo "Valid";
else
  echo "Invalid";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer. I tried your code, but i also tried the same with the UTF8 text from my pastebin above. It displays Valid. From where is coming the invalid 0xe3 0x2e 0x2e when inserting the text in SQL ?

Comment: @AlessandroGiuliani: your pastebin is valid because it never contains the invalid sequence. It's not clear how it's related to your question.

Comment: my pastebin contains the string which provokes the SQL error i described when i try to insert it. SQL tells the valid string contains the invalid sequence.

Comment: @AlessandroGiuliani: then it is the process that converts and injects these contents into a SQL query or a SQL parameter that is buggy. None of that pastebin should ever lead to a  `0xe3 0x2e 0x2e` sequence.

Comment: I found the problem, my truncate function divides utf8 character and so corrupts it. I fixed it with this : http://pastebin.com/V1Lbzgga